# "Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'" when trying to NPM publish

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a project I'm trying to publish as an npm module. It all runs correctly on my computer, and when I import it in a different folder, I can use it without any problems, but npm publish gives me this:

```
npm ERR! Class constructor  cannot be invoked without 'new'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/forrest/.npm/_logs/2017-11-09T13_21_57_362Z-debug.log
```

Honestly, I don't even know where to look for this kind of error - I'm pretty sure my code isn't missing any 'new' keywords, since it runs correctly before I try to publish. If it's an npm specific problem, I haven't been able to search up anything.

How can I fix this error and publish successfully? Failing that, what kind of a problem is it and where in my code should I look?

Here's that log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'publish' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.6.0
4 verbose npm-session 5adaf2e8823e5058
5 verbose publish [ '.' ]
6 info lifecycle Meristem@1.0.0~prepublish: Meristem@1.0.0
7 info lifecycle Meristem@1.0.0~prepare: Meristem@1.0.0
8 info lifecycle Meristem@1.0.0~prepublishOnly: Meristem@1.0.0
9 info lifecycle Meristem@1.0.0~prepack: Meristem@1.0.0
10 verbose tar pack [ '/var/folders/29/p2_sljq17376p_ycszkbx9rr0000gn/T/npm-35498-ea084a31/tmp/packing-340ae87b/package.tgz',
10 verbose tar pack   '.' ]
11 verbose tarball /var/folders/29/p2_sljq17376p_ycszkbx9rr0000gn/T/npm-35498-ea084a31/tmp/packing-340ae87b/package.tgz
12 verbose folder .
13 verbose stack TypeError: Class constructor  cannot be invoked without 'new'
13 verbose stack     at pack_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/tar.js:213:15)
13 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/tar.js:45:7
13 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:115:5
13 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:402:5
13 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:357:45)
13 verbose stack     at final (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:400:3)
13 verbose stack     at then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:160:5)
13 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:348:12
13 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
13 verbose stack     at tryToString (fs.js:514:3)
13 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:502:12)
14 verbose cwd /Users/forrest/web-projects/meristem
15 verbose Darwin 14.5.0
16 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "publish"
17 verbose node v8.6.0
18 verbose npm  v5.5.1
19 error Class constructor  cannot be invoked without 'new'
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

And [here's the code I'm trying to publish](https://github.com/ForrestWeiswolf/Meristem).

Comment: Please include the offending code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what kind of a problem is it and where in my code should I look?

By trying the [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack) command (which creates a tarball of a package but doesn't publish it) on a simple test folder without a valid package.json but none of my code in it, I was able to discover that this was a problem with NPM itself, not with my code.

> How can I fix this error and publish successfully?

Although I had updated NPM shortly before attempting to publish, I did so again (with `npm install npm@latest -g`), and this seems to have fixed the problem.